# How to use Tkinter after() method?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a problem using the `after` method in `Tkinter`.

The plan is to print `i` with interval of one second. I checked whether the `after` method is suitable, but I don't know exactly.

Here is the code.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from Tkinter import *
import time

root = Tk()
root.title("Program")
root['background'] ='gray'

def command_Print():
    for i in range(0, 10, 1):
        time.sleep(1)
        Label0.after(1)
        Labelvar.set(i)

Labelvar = StringVar()
Labelvar.set(u'original value')
Frame0 = Frame(root)
Frame0.place(x=0, y=0, width=100, height=50)
Label0 = Label(Frame0, textvariable=Labelvar, anchor='w')
Label0.pack(side=LEFT)


Frame_I = Frame(root)
Frame_I.place(x = 100, y = 0, width=100, height=70)
Button_I = Button(Frame_I, text = "Button" , width = 100, height=70, command = command_Print)
Button_I.place(x=0, y=0)
Button_I.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W, pady=4)
Button_I.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `time.sleep()` at all in Tkinter applications. Have the callback schedule a call to itself with `after()`.

```
def command_Print(counter=0):
    Labelvar.set(counter)
    if counter < 10:
        root.after(1000, lambda: command_Print(counter+1))
```

Also, `range(0, 10, 1)` is just `range(10)`. There's no need to repeat the defaults.

Comment: In this specific case you don't need lambda. You can do `root.after(1000, command_Print, counter+1)` which I think is a bit easier to read. Lots of people have problems grokking `lambda`.

Answer (score 7):

`after` with a single argument (eg: `after(10)`) is the same as calling `time.sleep`, and should generally be avoided. Since it puts your GUI to sleep, your GUI won't be able to respond to *any* events (including requests by the user or OS to refresh or resize the window)

When you call `after` with two or more arguments, the second argument is a reference to a function you want to call in the future. All remaining arguments will be passed to that function.

Tkinter maintains a queue of events. `mainloop` is the function that watches that queue and runs events as they come in. When you call `after`, the function you requested is simply added to the queue with a timestamp. When it is ready to be processed, tkinter will call the function and pass in the arguments. It's as simple as that.