# How to use the after method to make a callback run periodically?

Tags: python, tkinter

With tkinter, how can I use the `after` method to make a function run periodically?

For instance, I have a `speak` function that only prints something in the console:

```
def speak():
    print("Hello, world!")
```

How can I use the `after` method to call the `speak` function every second?

Comment: This question is intended to be canonical for the questions related to the `after` method in tkinter. Please check the answer below that comes with it. Examples of hardly-canonical questions related to that topic: [How to use Tkinter after() method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37748729/how-to-use-tkinter-after-method), [tkinter: how to use after method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25753632/tkinter-how-to-use-after-method)

Comment: This question has been asked and answered many times. Instead of creating a new question, why not edit one of the existing answers to be more canonical?

Comment: @BryanOakley Well, I wanted to do so, but the questions were not quite canonical, and generally related to a precise problem, which it would have not been appropriated to edit. So, I decided to write a straightforward question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Note: the following code is written and tested in Python 3.5. Minor changes might be needed, for instance, when calling `super`.*

The [documentation](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.after-method) describes the `Widget.after` method as follows:

> **after(delay_ms, callback=None, *args)**
>
> Registers an alarm callback that is called after a given time.

---

**Scheduling a function**

The `after` method is primarily used to schedule a function call after a given delay. For instance, the following code schedules a call to a function after one second:

```
import tkinter as tk

def speak():
    print("Hello world!")

root = tk.Tk()
root.after(1000, speak)

# Output
Hello world!
```

---

**Making a function run periodically**

In order to make a function run periodically, one can make it call itself at the end of its own body. However, `after` is a method from the `Widget` class, so a widget is needed. Therefore, the best choice is generally to put the scheduled function inside of a class extending `Widget`.

The following code prints `"Hello world!"` every other second in the console.

```
import tkinter as tk

class Foo(tk.Tk):
    def periodically_speak(self):
        print("Hello world!")
        self.after(2000, self.periodically_speak)

foo = Foo()
foo.periodically_speak()
```

---

**Using parameters**

One might want to pass parameters to a method that runs periodically. For this purpose, the `after` method unpacks every parameter after the callback as the parameters to pass to the callback. For instance, `root.after(1000, foo, a, b, c)` will schedule a call to `foo(a, b, c)`. The following example shows a use of this feature to determine the behaviour of the function.

```
import tkinter as tk

class Foo(tk.Tk):
    def periodically_speak(self, text):
        print(text)
        self.after(2000, self.periodically_speak, text)

foo = Foo()
foo.periodically_speak("Good night world!")
```

---

**Canceling a call**

The `after` methods returns a string, that corresponds to the call's id. It can be passed to the `after_cancel` method, in order to cancel a call that was scheduled.

The following example will start printing `"Hello world!"` every second, but will stop when pressing the button.

```
import tkinter as tk

class Foo(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.callId = None
        self.button = tk.Button(self, text="Stop", command=self.stop)
        self.button.pack()

    def periodically_speak(self):
        print("Hello world!")
        self.callId = self.after(2000, self.periodically_speak)

    def stop(self):
        if self.callId is not None:
            self.after_cancel(self.callId)

foo = Foo()
foo.periodically_speak()
```

---

**Side notes**

The following points should be kept in mind.

- The `after` method does not guarantee that the callback will be called *exactly* after the given delay, but *at least* after it. As a consequence, `after` should not be used where precision is required.
- It might be tempting to use `time.sleep` in order to schedule or periodically run a function. This must be avoided when working on a GUI, because `sleep` will pause the current thread, which most of the time is the main thread. For example, this could halt the refresh of the widgets, the program would stop responding.

Comment: Your very first answer isn't very canonical. You're using a lambda, when lambda is unnecessary and possibly misleading. Beginners may grab ahold of that first example and think that's how you're supposed to use `after`.

Comment: @BryanOakley Fair point. A few of us in the [SO Python chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python) who are familiar with Tkinter intend to look at this Q+A pair over the next few days and offer constructive criticism to bring it up to scratch.

Comment: @BryanOakley You're right, I edited that point. As PM 2Ring said, feel free to edit this post, I only want this to be helpful :)