# Periodic message Box in python

Tags: python, tkinter

I am new at python. I am using python 2.7. I want to have messagebox to notify me on every 50 seconds.
when I write this:

```
import sys
import time
import threading

if sys.version_info < (3,0):
        import Tkinter as tkinter
        import tkMessageBox as mbox
else:
        import tkinter
        import tkinter.messagebox as mbox

window = tkinter.Tk()
window.wm_withdraw()

def loop():
    threading.Timer(20.0, loop).start()
    mbox.showinfo('my app',time.ctime())

loop()
```

But when I press OK application freeze. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Take a look at `window.mainloop()`...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use the after method to make a periodical call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44085554/how-to-use-the-after-method-to-make-a-periodical-call)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to call `window.mainloop()`.
This method triggers the main loop of the widget, which processes the events, and allows interaction with the widget and its children.

In addition, you should use the `after` widget method rather than other timers.
This method allows you to schedule a call to a method.
You might wan to have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44085554/7051394) for a more complete explanation of the `after` method.

The following code implements the `loop` function with the `after` method, and runs the main loop by calling `window.mainloop()`.

```
def loop(root):
    mbox.showinfo('my app',time.ctime())
    root.after(50000, lambda: loop(root))

window = tkinter.Tk()
window.wm_withdraw()

loop(window)
window.mainloop()
```

Note that the `loop` function takes a widget as parameters, that will be your `window`.
This is needed, because the `after` method needs to be called on a widget.

Additionally, the `after` method takes a callback as second parameter, and I found it easier to pass it as a `lambda` function.
The latter is tantamount to calling `root.after(50000, f)` where `f` has been defined by `def f(): return loop(root)`.

Comment: approved this answer.  Can you tell me where I can see " threading.Timer vs after method"

Comment: @VladimirYanakiev I'm not sure if there is any explicit reason *against* `threading.Timer`, but since `tkinter` provides a way to handle scheduling, it should be used for the sake of uniformity. The fewer modules you use, the more constancy and compatibility you can expect across the functions.