# how to change the frames in tkinter using time and without button command

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am currently working on a GUI where I want my GUI to stay 5 seconds on the last frame, and then come back from the last frame to the first frame without any interaction.

If I use the `after` widget method, then the timer starts from the beginning of the application.
If I put it inside a method, and if I call that method, the same behaviour ocurs. On the other hand, if I call that function through a button, it works as expected.

**Controller**

```
# The code for changing pages was derived from:
  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7546050/switch-between-two-frames-in-tkinter
# License: http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/   

import tkinter as tk


LARGE_FONT= ("Verdana", 12)


class SeaofBTCapp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = tk.Frame(self)

        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)

        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}

        for F in (StartPage, PageOne, PageTwo):

            frame = F(container, self)

            self.frames[F] = frame

            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):

        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()
```

**`StartPage` class**

```
class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Start Page", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

        button = tk.Button(self, text="Visit Page 1",
                        command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageOne))
        button.pack()

        button2 = tk.Button(self, text="Visit Page 2",
                        command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageTwo))
        button2.pack()
```

**`PageOne` class**

```
class PageOne(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Page One!!!", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Back to Home",
                        command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        button1.pack()

        button2 = tk.Button(self, text="Page Two",
                        command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageTwo))
        button2.pack()
```

**`PageTwo` class**

```
class PageTwo(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Page Two!!!", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Back to Home",
                        command=lambda:self.start_reset())
        button1.pack()

        button2 = tk.Button(self, text="Page One",
                        command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageOne))
        button2.pack()
        # self.after(5000,self.controller.show_frame(StartPage)) works only
        # once and the time starts from the start of the GUI and after 5000ms it takes
        # the gui to the start page no matter what  
    def start_reset(self):
        self.after(5000,self.controller.show_frame(StartPage))


app = SeaofBTCapp()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Related: [How to use the after method to make a periodical call?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44085554/7051394)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several place where you can put your call to the `after` method.
To me, it makes more sense if it's placed in the controller class, because it is meant to manage the components.

One direct way to achieve this is to complete the `SeaofBTCapp.show_frame` method:

```
def show_frame(self, cont):
    frame = self.frames[cont]
    frame.tkraise()

    if cont == PageTwo:
        self.after(5000, self.show_frame, StartPage)
```

When the `show_frame` method is called, a call to `show_frame` with `StartPage` as parameter is scheduled.

Comment: thank you so much for your answer. Your answer was very nicely described and was really helpful. Many many thanks