# Python / tkinter: Events: call a function by mouse on widget

Tags: python, events, button, tkinter, label

I would like to improve my program, I just do not know how.

I want that an event starts, when the users mouse is over a **tkinter**'s widget.

This...

```
button.bind("<Motion>", lambda eff: callback())
```

... is working, but the users needs to move the mouse for call the function.

Is there a way to start, for example, every x seconds the function while the mouse is over the widget?

I need it to display an integer that changes constantly as text of a button or a label while the mouse is over the button or label.

Do you have any Ideas?

Thanks for your attention,

Lukas

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can bind a function to `<Enter>` to trigger a function when the mouse enters a widget, and you can bind to `<Leave>` to trigger when it leaves.

The `<Enter>` binding can run a function that starts updating the label periodically using `after`. The `<Leave>` binding can set a flag that the update function checks in order to know to stop updating.

There are many questions and answers on this site about using `after` to do something periodically. For example, [How to use the after method to make a callback run periodically?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44085554/7432)